# Seeking recommendation for 3-tiered LINQ Query in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, join, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a LINQ query that is correctly retrieving all relevant poll questions and their associated responses.  In this query, I'm using the .Include() method to retrieve the responses.  I like this approach because it makes the code in my View simple -- basically I have a @foreach for the responses nested inside a @foreach for the questions.

Now, I'd like to add response-specific information such as # of votes today, # of votes this week and # of votes overall.  Again, these would be retrieved and displayed for each response of each question.

Is there an efficient LINQ solution that would allow me to continue using my .Include() method and my nested @foreach loops or do I need to scrap the .Include() method and use joins to pull everything together?

If it matters for performance reasons, this is being written in .net MVC-3.

Thanks in advance for your opinions/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> I like this approach because it makes the code in my View simple -- basically I have a @foreach for the responses nested inside a @foreach for the questions.

Personally I wouldn't be satisfied with this. Why writing loops in your view when you can use Display Temapltes? As far as your question about including the # of votes today, # of votes this week and # of votes overall is concerned the answer, as always, is to use a view model which is specifically tailored to the needs of the view:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public int VotesToday { get; set; }
    public int VotesThisWeek { get; set; }
    public int TotalVotes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ResponseViewModel> { get; set; }
}
```

then you would pass an `IEnumerable<QuestionViewModel>` to your view and it will look like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppName.Models.QuestionViewModel>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

and in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/QuestionViewModel.cshtml`

```
@model AppName.Models.QuestionViewModel
<div>@Model.VotesToday</div>
<div>@Model.VotesThisWeek</div>
<div>@Model.TotalVotes</div>
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ResponseViewModel)
```

and in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ResponseViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model AppName.Models.ResponseViewModel
<div>@Model.Body</div>
```

Now, that's a clean view.

Let's move to the controller now:

```
public class QuestionsController: Controller
{
    private readonly IQuestionsRepository _repository;
    public QuestionsController(IQuestionsRepository _repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Question> model = _repository.GetQuestions();
        IEnumerable<QuestionViewModel> viewModel = Mapper
            .Map<IEnumerable<Question>, IEnumerable<QuestionViewModel>>(model);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Here we have abstracted the data access away into a repository so that the controller should never know anything about EF or whatever data access technology you are using. A controller should only know about your model, your view model and abstraction of how to manipulate the model (in this case the repository interface).

As far as the conversion between the your model and the view model is concerned you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) (the `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>` part in my example).

As far as the repository is concerned, that's an implementation detail: whether you perform one or three queries to your database it's up to you. All that's needed is that you are capable of aggregating the required information.

Comment: Thanks Darin.  I need to rework your example before I can honestly say that I understand it.  For one, the "Votes Today, etc" seems like it should be in the ResponseViewModel as they are values of a response, not a question.  1 question has many responses and each response has those values.  That said, I think I'm following your general thought but I've never used DisplayForModel() nor Mapper.Map, so I'll need to research.   Given your approach, I'm not sure if my original question has been answered or if it is no longer applicable.  I'll try your approach and see what happens.  Thanks again.

Comment: I think I understand your response, but I don't think it answered my initial question.  You said "whether you perform one or three queries to you database it's up to you".  That's at the heart of my question.  How would I do it in a single query.  How would I efficiently do it in 3 queries?  I appreciate your response and I'm going to try that approach, but I'm still stuck on the data retrieval step.  Best,

Comment: @karman, I am not a specialist with EF and cannot answer how to perform one query instead of three. The idea is to perform SQL join. This is now an EF specific question and totally unrelated to MVC. In my answer I showed how to abstract your data access logic from your MVC application.